# Does the status "mal v'lo taval" apply to women?

Tags: women, conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah, grapes-wine, mikvah-ritual-bath

In a number of circumstances, the halachic status of מל ולא טבל ("circumcized but not immersed in a mikveh") takes on significance.

For instance, regarding a nochri touching wine, the Shulchan Aruch (YD 124:2) notes that the touch of a מל ולא טבל does not render the wine unfit for benefit, and according to the Ramo (as read by the Shach) even drinking such wine is allowed.

How does this status apply to a potential female convert? Is there some intermediate state where a female convert is considered 'partially converted' such that wine touched by her can still be used?

Is the status of מל ולא טבל just a general description of being "in the process of conversion" and not to be taken literally, in which case it applies equally to men and women?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Shach Yoreh Deah 124:4 he makes a distinction between a ger toshav and ger shmal v'lo taval that it goes by when they are mekabal the mitzvos. L'choyra this inyun should be the same by a women when she is mekabal the mitzvos. The Shulchan Aruch mentions mal v'lo taval because that is a novel case of having milah without having a kabbalah yet.

Comment: That is the Shach quoted in the question. But the question is whether this kabalah is talking about the technical case of a man, or more generally talking about the implicit kabalah of anyone in the process of conversion. I take it from your answer you think it is the technical case, but is there any discussion of this anywhere? I ask because I heard people say that the term "mal v'lo taval" is used in a non-technical sense, but perhaps they were mistaken.

Comment: From the way the Shach is explaining it,it seems that it goes by kabbalah and this would include a women .The only case of a women is tevilah which comes with a kabbala,but by a man there is a case of having a milah and no kabbalah which is a in between case. Hope I was more clear.